# DIV element space problemo

Tags: css, html, navigation

This is the first time i'm learning HTML and CSS (started 4 days ago). I was making a test site just for fun and came across a problem. There is a element blocking some text from going into the place i want. I know that it's the navigation bar, because it fixes the problem when I delete it, but I do not want to delete it. How to please fix it?
Sorry for any typos, i'm not a native english-speaker.
NOTE=THIS IS JUST A TEST SITE. I KNOW THAT THE IMAGES ARE COPYRIGHTED.
http://s9.postimg.org/8mokg65db/Optimized_Sk_rmavbild_2013_10_29_kl_20_33_10.jpg
Code:HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<title>Hem - Tupac Shakur Fansida</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
</body>
<div class=wrapper>
!-----------------------------------! NAVIGATION
<div id="navmenudiv">
<ul id=”navmenu”>
<li><a href=index.html>Start</a></li>
<li><a href=about.html>Om</a></li>
<li><a href=”#”>Död</a></li>
<li><a href=”#”>Lever han?</a></li>
<li><a href=”#”>Diskografi</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
!-----------------------------------! NAVIGATION
<p>Den här sidan är till minne för Tupac Shakur, en av de bästa hip-hopparna genom tiderna. Jag vet att det redan finns många sådana sidor, men denna är helt och hållet på svenska och för med mina tankar också.</p>
<p>Tupac föddes den 16:de Juni 1971 i Harlem, New York. Hans mamma, Afeni Shakur, var fattig och medlem i den svarta kriminella gruppen Svarta Pantrarna. När han var 12 år började han på Baltimore School for the Arts.</p>
<p>Tupac är den bäst-säljande artisten genom tiderna och det finns få artister som inte känner till hans stora namn. Han sköts ihjäl av okända gärningmän den 7 september 1996.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#navmenudiv {position:relative;bottom:53px;right:4px;}
#navmenudiv ul {padding:0}
#navmenudiv li {display:inline;}
#navmenudiv li a {font-family:Helvetica;font-size:11px;text-decoration:none;
float:left;padding:10px;background-color:#2175bc;color:#fff;}
#navmenudiv ul li a:hover {background-color:#2586d7;margin-top:-2px;
padding-bottom:12px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to ensure there's enough room would be to put the style `"clear: left"` on the div with text on it, that will make sure there are no floats to the left.  Another way would be to make the nav bar `"position: absolute"`, but that requires the parent be `"position: relative"` or absolute itself.

Comment: Great! That along with some "margin" and "position" got the text to exactly where I wanted! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the `<body>` tag at the eighth line of the HTML code.

Comment: You are closing body tag without even creating it :). Its pair tag you have to declare it by typing <body> and close it by </body> at the end of body of your html document. so its like <body> ..code... </body>

Comment: Haha! That was weird, I knew that, just a miss or something. But how did it worked without a opening tag?! :) But it didn't affect my problem.

Comment: I guess the browser found it out and managed to show the website like it was supposed to be. Sorry to hear it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the menu to overlap the image are so you could change your css for #navmenudiv to

```
    #navmenudiv {position:relative;right:4px; display:inline-block; margin-top:-50px}
```

This will clear the text onto the next line by setting `display:inline-block` and then use `margin-top:-50px`to create a negative margin pulling the menu up over the image.

(You will need to play with the size of the negative margin to achieve the layout you want)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue (it's hard to tell because we don't have the full source code) is just a matter of clearing your floats for that paragraph below the navigation ([enter link description here](http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/)).

So here is a quick [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXQ2C/2/) to show you my revised code that puts the paragraph text beneath your navigation, and also corrects some of your divs and links that do not have quotes aroud them.

Here is the revised **HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="navmenudiv">
        <ul id="navmenu">
            <li><a href="index.html">Start</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="about.html">Om</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Död</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Lever han?</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Diskografi</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p>Den här sidan är till minne för Tupac Shakur, en av de bästa hip-hopparna genom tiderna. Jag vet att det redan finns många sådana sidor, men denna är helt och hållet på svenska och för med mina tankar också.</p>
    <p>Tupac föddes den 16:de Juni 1971 i Harlem, New York. Hans mamma, Afeni Shakur, var fattig och medlem i den svarta kriminella gruppen Svarta Pantrarna. När han var 12 år började han på Baltimore School for the Arts.</p>
    <p>Tupac är den bäst-säljande artisten genom tiderna och det finns få artister som inte känner till hans stora namn. Han sköts ihjäl av okända gärningmän den 7 september 1996.</p>
    </div<!-- .container -->
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* General */
.clear { clear: both; }

/* Navigation */
 #navmenudiv {
    position:relative;
}
#navmenudiv ul {
    padding:0
}
#navmenudiv li {
    display:inline;
}
#navmenudiv li a {
    font-family:Helvetica;
    font-size:11px;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#2175bc;
    color:#fff;
}
#navmenudiv ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#2586d7;
    margin-top:-2px;
    padding-bottom:12px;
}
```

Hopefully that fixes the issue you are having.